# OOP form builder

Tags: php, formbuilder

I am considering implementing simple form builder in PHP OOP and integrate it into my MVC Framework.

Do you find form builder useful or is it pointless?

Do you prefer typing in HTML Form manually?

Comment: zend_form in zend framework will be good

Comment: The Symfony 2 form package is also quite nice though integrating it into an existing mvc frame work might be more trouble than it is worth.  It is worth reading the manual for ideas: (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form builders are useful but they can be a little complex to use. Personally i used [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html) and was very happy with it, even if they were a little hard to style

Comment: Have you seen this? http://docs.fuelphp.com/classes/form.html - The coding style look simple and easy to use than Zend_Form

Comment: @user791022 you should choose a form builder that suits your needs, in my experience using form builder is better than writing forms "by hand". If Zend_Form looks too heavy for your needs, use the other one! :)

Comment: How bizarre. I was just reading about Zend Form as a standalone. Looks like a good suggestion. +1

Comment: @Darragh i used it as a standalone in more than one project and it worked pefectly